# Hide/Show <div> during update based on condition reactjs

Tags: reactjs

During my display modal(update). I want to show/hide a `<div>` based on the value of one column.

See my code:

```
const [showDateTimeDiv, setshowDateTimeDiv] = useState(false)
const [modalEdit, setModalEdit] = useState(false); 
const [details, setDetails] = useState({
   ID: '',
   TYPE : '',
   ....
})
const openCloseModalEdit =()=>
{
  setModalEdit(!modalEdit)
}
.....
const bodyUpdate = (
  {showDateTimeDiv &&
   <div>
    ....
   </div>
   }
)

return(
<div>
   <Modal
    open = {modalEdit}
    onClose = {openCloseModalEdit} >
    {bodyUpdate}
   </Modal>
</div>
```

What I want to do is when `details.TYPE = 'A'` then setshowDateTimeDiv(true). I tried to put this inside the `openCloseModalEdit` however, on the first open, it did not take effect, it take effect on the second trigger of `openCloseModalEdit`.

Note: since this is an update `details` will have value upon opening the `modaledit`

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useEffect can solve this problem.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    details.TYPE === 'A' ? setshowDateTimeDiv(true) : setshowDateTimeDiv(false);
},[details]);
```

Please try to use this and let me know the result.